# Install OpenCV on Arch Linux for C++ and Python using `pacman`

Tags: arch-linux, gtk, opencv

I want to install OpenCV (with GTK) latest stable version on my Arch Linux. I know how to manually build and install the library, but I don't want to go through all that. Is there a way to get it via `pacman`. I know that packages are available for `qt` but its causing issues for me. I am using `Gnome`.

Comment: Strictly answering your question, pacman lets you install packages from the official repositories only, without affecting how packages are compiled. You may search the [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/) for an alternative version or file bug reports about the issues you are facing with the official package or take advantage of the [ABS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System) to compile your own version. You may want to reword your question a bit, to clarify what kind of solution would be acceptable/preferable to you.

Comment: @fra-san I went through a long list of AUR packages but couldn't find any package with gtk support. But I am not sure about [opencv-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/opencv-git/), it has gtk in its dependencies list. Also, I am not sure about its stability. Can you confirm?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unfortunately not able to comment on that, nor on other AUR packages.

Comment: I am using [opencv-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/opencv-git/) package. I have tweaked the `PKGBUILD` file a bit to support `GTK` instead of `QT`.

Comment: Glad to know that! If that solution works for you it would be great if you could post it as an answer to your own question, to make it clear that your problem is solved (or at least that you've found something working). Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a package for `opecv` in either the main repo or aur that supports `GTK` by default. So, I decided to use the `opencv-git`. I added the required flags to the `PKGBUILD` file in `cmake_opts` which are:

```
-DWITH_QT=OFF
-DWITH_GTK=ON
```

and build the package just as usual.